# Problem with sending data by post, router error

Tags: angular7, angular-router

I can't send data to backend I don't know why, the problem in the console looks like that exactly at the login and register component this same issue is appearing. Maybe the ngsubmit is formated wrong but I don't know how to post the (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"  by the patter that it needs to represent.
This is the error in the console and the components which I'm using.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'router' of undefined
    at AuthInceptor (auth.interceptor.ts:11)
    at eval (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at _callFactory (core.js:21283)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21237)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21198)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
```

auth.service.ts

```js
constructor(private router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    LogIn(email: string, password: string) {
        const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'No-Auth': 'True'});
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.apiAddress + 'account/login', {
            Email: email,
            Password: password
            }, {headers: reqHeader})
        .catch((e: any) => Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(e)));
    }
    Register(name: string, email: string, password: string, role: string) {
        const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'No-Auth': 'True'});
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.apiAddress + 'account/register', {
            Name: name,
            Email: email,
            Password: password,
            Role: role
            }, {headers: reqHeader})
        .catch((e: any) => Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(e)));
    }
errorHandler(error: any): void {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

auth.inceptor.ts

```js
constructor(private router: Router) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') === 'True') {
            return next.handle(req.clone());
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
            const clonedreq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
            });
            return next.handle(clonedreq)
                .do(
                succ => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.status === 401) {
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                    }
                }
                );
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
    }
```

log-in form

```html
<form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(email.value, password.value)" #f="ngForm">
  <mat-card-content>
      <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Email" #email ngModel name="email" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" #password ngModel type="password" name="password" required>
        </mat-form-field></td>
      </tr></table>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit"  color="primary">Login</button>
    <div *ngIf="isLoginError" class="red-text center error-message">Error Incorrect email or password</div>
  </mat-card-actions>
</form>
```

Submit function

```js
onSubmit(email, password): void {
    this.authService.LogIn(email, password)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token);
      localStorage.setItem('role', data.role);
      this.router.navigate(['../Home']);
      console.log(data);
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.isLoginError = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `injector`?

Comment: I find out that in app.module.ts I've said useFactory instead of useClass and that causes the issue...